# ContentTools editor update src of fixture image

Tags: javascript, html, image, content-management-system, fixed

A few days ago I needed an HTML editor and found Contenttools. Really awesome library, but I have some problems with adding the functionality I need.

I'm trying to make an image editable, but it can't be removed/resized (and always has a fixed size!). I'm trying to make it so you can click on an image which opens the ImageDialog, where you can clear out the current image and insert a new one (replace src-attribute). I did some coding and it looks like it works, but I have some problems with the undo/redo and stopping the editor.

**Problem 1**
When I replace the image, then press undo and after that redo. Everything works as expected in the browser, but when I hit save there is no Ajax call going out. It looks like Contenttools doesn't see the image as being changed after an undo/redo.

**Problem 2**
When I cancel the Contenttools editor the image stays on the screen as an generated DIV from Contenttools. I doensn't revert back to the normal image tag, so it stays editable all the time.

I have a simplified version of my code added down below. I hope someone can steer me in the right direction. I have the feeling that it has to be some small issue, not doing a method call or something.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="content-tools.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="img/old.jpeg" data-fixture class="width480 height380 fixture-image">

        <script src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="content-tools.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var editor;

/* Overwrite revertToSnapshot method */
var editorApp = ContentTools.EditorApp.getCls();
editorApp.prototype.revertToSnapshot = function (snapshot, restoreEditable) {
    if(!restoreEditable) restoreEditable = true;

    for(name in this._regions) {
        var region = this._regions[name];

        if($(this._regions[name]._domElement).hasClass('fixture-image')) {
            var image = $($.parseHTML(snapshot.regions[name]));
            region.children[0].unmount();
            region.children[0].attr('src', image.attr('src'));
            region.children[0].taint();
        } else {
            for(child in region.children) {
                region.children[child].unmount();
            }

            region.domElement().innerHTML = snapshot.regions[name];
        }
    }

    if(restoreEditable) {
        if(ContentEdit.Root.get().focused()) {
            ContentEdit.Root.get().focused().blur();
        }

        this._regions = {};

        this.syncRegions();

        this.history.replaceRegions(this._regions);

        this.history.restoreSelection(snapshot);

        this._inspector.updateTags();
    }
};

/* Load the editor */
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    editor = ContentTools.EditorApp.get();
    editor.init('*[data-editable], [data-fixture]', 'data-editable-id');

    editor.addEventListener('saved', function (ev) {
        var name, payload, regions, xhr;

        // Check that something changed
        regions = ev.detail().regions;
        if (Object.keys(regions).length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Set the editor as busy while we save our changes
        this.busy(true);

        // Collect the contents of each region into a FormData instance
        payload = {};
        for (name in regions) {

            if (regions.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                payload[name] = regions[name];
            }
        }

        console.log(payload);
    });

    new FixturedImageEditor();
});

/* Object for handling fixture images */
function FixturedImageEditor()
{
    this.events();
}

FixturedImageEditor.prototype.events = function(){
    var self = this;

    $("body").on("click", ".ce-element--type-image.fixture-image", function() {
        var $el = $(this),
            image = ContentEdit.Root.get().focused();

        var dimensions = {
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        };

        $.each($el.attr('class').split(" "), function(key, value){
            if(value.indexOf("width") === 0) {
                dimensions.width = value.replace("width", "");
            } else if(value.indexOf("height") === 0) {
                dimensions.height = value.replace("height", "");
            }
        });

        self.fire($el, image, dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
    });
}

FixturedImageEditor.prototype.fire = function($el, image, width, height){

    var dialog = new ContentTools.ImageDialog(),
        modal = new ContentTools.ModalUI(false, false);

    dialog.fixedWidth = width;
    dialog.fixedHeight = height;

    this.addEventListeners(dialog, modal, $el, image);

    editor.attach(modal);
    editor.attach(dialog);
    dialog.show();
    modal.show();

    dialog.populate(image._attributes.src, [dialog.fixedWidth, dialog.fixedHeight]);

    $(dialog._domInsert).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(dialog._domCrop).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(dialog._domRotateCW).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(dialog._domRotateCCW).css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

FixturedImageEditor.prototype.addEventListeners = function(dialog, modal, $el, image) {
    var self = this;

    dialog.addEventListener('cancel', function(){
        modal.hide();
        dialog.hide();
    });

    dialog.addEventListener('save', function(e){
        self.save(e, dialog, modal, $el, image);
    });

    dialog.addEventListener('imageuploader.fileready', function(e){
        $(dialog._domInsert).css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
}

FixturedImageEditor.prototype.save = function(e, dialog, modal, $el, image) {
    detail = e.detail();
    imageURL = detail.imageURL;
    imageSize = detail.imageSize;
    imageAttrs = detail.imageAttrs;

    image.attr('src', imageURL);
    image.attr('alt', imageAttrs.alt);
    image.mount();
    image.taint();

    modal.hide();
    dialog.hide();
}

ContentTools.IMAGE_UPLOADER = imageUploader;

function imageUploader(dialog) {
    var image, xhr, xhrComplete, xhrProgress;

    // Set up the event handlers
    dialog.addEventListener('imageuploader.cancelupload', function () {
        // Cancel the current upload

        // Stop the upload
        if (xhr) {
            xhr.upload.removeEventListener('progress', xhrProgress);
            xhr.removeEventListener('readystatechange', xhrComplete);
            xhr.abort();
        }

        // Set the dialog to empty
        dialog.state('empty');
    });

    dialog.addEventListener('imageuploader.clear', function () {
        // Clear the current image
        dialog.clear();
        image = null;
    });

    dialog.addEventListener('imageuploader.fileready', function (ev) {
        var image = {
            size: [480, 380],
           url: 'img/ajax-new.png'
        };

    // Populate the dialog
    dialog.populate(image.url, image.size);
});

dialog.addEventListener('imageuploader.save', function () {
    dialog.save(
        'img/ajax-new.png',
        [100,100],
        {}
    );

    // Set the dialog to busy while the rotate is performed
    dialog.busy(true);
});
```

}

Comment: Problem 1 is an issue with the library itself. For more info: https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/issues/301
If somebody can still help me with Problem 2, that would be great.

Comment: Hi @Chris are you getting any error messages in the console at all? Is it possible you could put a fiddle or gist together I can use to replicate the problem and try to help (I'm the author of CT and if I can help resolve I will)

Comment: Ah looks like I can just use what you've posted above - will take a look now

Comment: OK really sorry Chris but I've spent 10 minutes trying to make the code above work and I can't at all, there's an input in the JS and the structure seems entirely wrong to me, I don't think the example you have posted is suitable for me to try and solve the issue as it doesn't initialize the editor and therefore I can't see the second problem you've mentioned. Ideally a working JSFiddle that made it easy to reproduce the error would be the most helpful next step for me.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, a JSFiddle can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/dd2hpko4/ Thx in advance

Comment: Hi @Chris - OK I had to modify the following, the editor's `saved` event listener to change the status of the ignition to non-busy after a save and  the fake image URL inserted to one that loaded. But the fiddle works for me, I edit the image by clicking it, clearing it, uploading a new image and saving it. I don't see the behaviour you describe on save, the div gets converted back to an img tag. I'm using Chrome, what browser are you using?